# Initialize integer variables in CyLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, coin-or

I'm currently using [`CyLP`](https://github.com/coin-or/CyLP/tree/master) package in Python for mixed-integer linear programming. However, I'm not able to initialize integer variables. According to the [documentation](http://mpy.github.io/CyLPdoc/modules/modeling.html#CyLP.py.modeling.CyLPModel.CyLPModel.addVariable), I have passed `isInt = True` to `addVariable` method but it does nothing.

A minimal example of my program is shown below. The optimal value should be 2 when `x = y = 1`, but the result is not as expected.

```py
import cylp
from cylp.cy import CyClpSimplex
print(cylp.__version__) # 0.91.0

s = CyClpSimplex()
x = s.addVariable('x', 1, isInt = True)
y = s.addVariable('y', 1, isInt = True)
s += x >= 0.5
s += y >= 0.7

s.objective = x + y
s.optimizationDirection = 'min'

s.primal()
# Clp3002W Empty problem - 0 rows, 2 columns and 0 elements
# Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 1.2

x_opt = s.primalVariableSolution['x'][0]
y_opt = s.primalVariableSolution['y'][0]
print(x_opt, y_opt) # 0.5, 0.7
```

Is there any other way to initialize integer variables in `CyLP`? Or I'm missing something about `addVariable` method?

By the way, I wonder what `Clp3002W Empty problem` means in the output of `s.primal()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit mean.

[Clp](https://github.com/coin-or/Clp) is a *Linear-Programming* solver while you are trying to do *Mixed-Integer-Programming*.

You will need to use [Cbc](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) which is built on top of Clp (same person / same people). I think, that one can recognize that most of this is a one-man project over decades (unintuitive design; maybe).

**Yes, CyLp is based on Cbc, but usage still needs care!**

Assuming, that your variable-definitions are okay (did not check), you will need to do something [like](https://github.com/sschnug/kemeny_ranking/blob/master/kemeny.py#L162):

```
# model = CyClpSimplex()                                           
# ...

cbcModel = model.getCbcModel()  # Clp -> Cbc model / LP -> MIP

status = cbcModel.solve()           #-> "Call CbcMain. Solve the problem
                                    #   "using the same parameters used
                                    #   "by CbcSolver."
                                    # This deviates from cylp's docs which are sparse!
                                    # -> preprocessing will be used and is very important!
```

See also [this wrapper](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/9eb348676f1cf12d55950878ffc23d9663c5e7bd/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/conic_solvers/cbc_conif.py#L160):

```
if data[s.BOOL_IDX] or data[s.INT_IDX]:
    # MIP
    # Convert model
    cbcModel = model.getCbcModel()

    # cylp: /cylp/cy/CyCbcModel.pyx#L134
    # Call CbcMain. Solve the problem using the same parameters used by
    # CbcSolver. Equivalent to solving the model from the command line
    # using cbc's binary.
    cbcModel.solve()
    status = cbcModel.status
else:
    # LP
    # cylp: /cylp/cy/CyClpSimplex.pyx
    # Run CLP's initialSolve. It does a presolve and uses primal or dual
    # Simplex to solve a problem.
    status = model.initialSolve()
```

I wrote these things a lot of time ago, therefore i cannot give you exact details (background behind these calls and the comments).

But in general: it's hard to grasp what exactly is happening internally in Cbc (although there was some work in improving the API i think; probably *NOT* reflected in Cylp though). For example: it's not trivial to use Cbc from code in the same way as the Cbc executable behaves.

> By the way, I wonder what Clp3002W Empty problem means in the output of s.primal().

> Clp3002W Empty problem - 0 rows, 2 columns and 0 elements

My interpretation:

Your (transformed) model has no constraints. You added constraints to enforce *variable-bounds* but Clp/Cbc is advanced enough (it's very very advanced) to transform these constraints into variable-bounds (no constraints anymore!), which are handled by special treatment in the Simplex-Routine.

```
0 rows = 0 constraints

0 elements = 0 non-zero elements in your constraint-matrix of size
        rows * cols = 0 * 2 = 0
```